# Error al intentar personalizar el usuario de django

Tags: python, django

Por primera vez estoy personalizando el registro de usuarios de django con AbstractBaseUser, modificando el modelo para mis necesidades, para poder conseguir esto estoy leyendo el codigo fuente de django, pero me estoy encontrando con un problema y es que al momento de crear un super usuario me genera un error en mi campo date_birth del modelo usuario el cual no puede ser nulo, pues el error es logico pues al momento de crearlo ese campo no lo asigno para un super usuario entonces se envia como nulo, pero en mi UserManager estoy recibiendo el diccionario extra_fields, el cual no se supone que tiene todos los campos de mi modelo, mire como lo declara django y ellos solo asignan blank=true, hice lo mismo para mis campos pero sigue generando el mismo error. 
Este es mi UserManager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, identity, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The email is required')

        if not identity:
            raise ValueError('The email is required')

        if identity > 10:
            raise ValueError('The identity not count correct')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, identity=identity, **extra_fields)
        user.password = make_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_user(self, email, identity=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, identity, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, identity=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self._create_user(email, identity, password, **extra_fields)
```

Este es mi User:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    date_birth = models.DateField(blank=True)
    identity = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['identity']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

Comment: Adjunta todo el error :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Permitir que `date_birth` sea *nullable*. Hasta ahora no lo estás haciendo. Recuerda que `blank=True` permite que el campo no sea obligatorio en las forms. Por lo tanto, haciendo lo siguiente obtendrás lo que deseas:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # ... 
    date_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    # ...
```

2. Proveer un valor por defecto para el campo `date_birth`.

```
from django.utils import timezone


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # ... 
    date_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, default=timezone.now)
    # ...
```

Ahora bien, te estarás preguntando: ¿Pero por qué en el código del modelo `User` de Django no hay ningún `null=True`?

Te explico: Los campos del modelo `User` son (por defecto):

- username (`CharField`, requerido)
- password (`CharField`, requerido)
- first_name (`CharField`, opcional)
- last_name (`CharField`, opcional)
- email (`EmailField`, opcional)
- is_staff (`BooleanField`, opcional con valor por defecto)
- is_active (`BooleanField`, opcional con valor por defecto)
- date_joined (`DateTimeField`, opcional con valor por defecto)

Ninguno es *nullable* (explícitamente) porque:

- O son requeridos.
- O son de tipo `CharField` (los cuales son *nullables* implícitamente. De hecho, es contraproducente, a menudo, declararlos explícitamente como `null=True`, tal como lo indica [la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#null))
- O tienen un valor por defecto.

---

Como nota final, estás tomando el camino más escabroso para extender el modelo `User`. Hay maneras mucho más sencillas, como lo indica el buen Vitor Freitas [en su blog](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html). Te sugiero tomar alguna de las alternativas allí planteadas.